# ¿me podrian dar una ayuda con una plantilla en un proyecto laravel?

Tags: laravel

Quisiera realizar la carga pero de la manera optima usando laravel. 
esta es la parte de la plantilla, en la parte en la que cargo el listado con php plano seria un menú que enviara a una vista donde se mostrará el contenido de ese objeto
**considerando que en la parte @yield('content') es una vista donde funciona un sistema de blog.**

```
    <section>
       <?php 
            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","blogradio");
            mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
            $peticion="SELECT * FROM grupos WHERE status='PUBLISHED'";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$peticion);

                while( $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado) ){

                echo '<a href='.$fila['slug'].'">'.$fila['name'].'</a>';
              }

          ?>

    </section>

    @yield('content')

    <section class="site-section testimonial-wrap" id="los-profesionales">
    </section
```

Quisiera realizar la carga pero de la manera optima usando laravel. considerando que en la parte **@yield('content')** es una vista donde funciona un sistema de blog.

Agradeceré mucho la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que tener tu vista principal con el yield como tienes ahora y extender la secundaria de esta haciendo uso de section para colocar en el lugar que anteriormente predefiniste.

Es mas fácil con un ejemplo

layout.blade.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<h1>A</h1>
@yield('content')
<h2>C</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

vista.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
<p>B</p>
@endsection
```

Si devolvemos view('vista') nos dará lo siguiente

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<h1>A</h1>
<p>B</p>
<h2>C</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

EDITADO:
Ahora bien, si quieres que en toda las vistas carguen ciertos datos, se pueden cargar los datos desde `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

Por ejemplo, ahora vamos a editar el código anterior para que muestre el numero de usuarios.

layout.blade.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<h1>{{ $usuarios }}</h1>

<h1>A</h1>
@yield('content')
<h2>C</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

AppServiceProvider.php

```
 view()->composer(['layout'], function ($view) {
            $view->with('usuarios', User::count())
        });
```

Si devolvemos view('vista') nos dará lo siguiente (suponiendo que tenemos 2 users)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<h1>2</h1>

<h1>A</h1>
<p>B</p>
<h2>C</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Gracias por reponder, en  la parte @yield(content) ya tengo un blog  que carga con la ruta y el primer controlador que puse. Lo que deseo es cargar una lista dinamica que esta en otra vista que funciona con la ruta y el segundo segundo controlador que puse.

Comment: Porque quieres usar 2 controladores a la vez?

Comment: hola que tal, voy a editar un ratito mi post!! le das una mirada a ver si me puedes iluminar!!!

Comment: aunque estaba viendo que en realidad lo que necesitaba era imprimir en el template la lista de mi base de datos, y que el controlador me serviría para dar vista a donde se dirija esa informacion que pienso convertir en enlaces

Comment: Te añadí otro ejemplo

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo Manuel, en la noche lo pruebo y comento mis resultados. Solo una consulta debo crear una ruta un controlador, una vista y las variables las llamo en el layout-plantilla correcto?. En la noche lo pruebo. Gracias

Comment: Hola Manuel, acabo de editar tu respuesta con lo que hice, todavía no me sale.

Comment: Nunca edites una respuesta ajena para eso, edita tu pregunta mejor